# Retornar resultado em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, preciso retornar um resultado em um input. como faço?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="cc-number" id="cc-number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" name="cc-flag" id="cc-flag" type="text">
</div>
```

Vou digitar no input **cc-number** e me retorna o resultado no **cc-flag**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var input = document.querySelector('input.cc-number')
var result = document.querySelector('input.cc-flag')

input.addEventListener('change', onInputChange)
input.addEventListener('input', onInputChange)

function onInputChange (e) {
  var cards = CardType.cardType(e.target.value)
  result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(cards)
}
```

**OBS**: Ele funciona corretamente retornando para um DIV. Mas preciso que volte para um INPUT

Comment: Você quer colocar o valor de um `input` dentro de outro `input`?

Comment: Isso mesmo... o primeiro input faz uma busca em um arquivo .js e retorna um valor. preciso que esse valor seja retornado dentro do input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `innerHTML` é para modificar o html que fica dentro de uma tag. O valor de um `input` fica em `value` e não em `innerHTML`, por isso não está conseguindo mudar.

Outra coisa, você não tem classes `.cc-number` e `.cc-flag`, mas sim ids. Então, no seu seletor, você deve colocar `#` no lugar de `.`.

Segue o exemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input#cc-number')
var result = document.querySelector('input#cc-flag')

input.addEventListener('change', onInputChange)
input.addEventListener('input', onInputChange)

function onInputChange (e) {
  var cards = CardType.cardType(e.target.value)
  result.value = cards
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="cc-number" id="cc-number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" name="cc-flag" id="cc-flag" type="text">
</div>

<script src="https://polvo-labs.github.io/card-type/dist/card-type.js"></script>
```

Comment: Não quero duplicar o valor em outra input... quero que o resultado apareça no input

Comment: Estou usando este exemplo: https://polvo-labs.github.io/card-type/example/ . Neste exemplo ele retorna dentro de uma div. Preciso que retorne dentro de input como disse acima

Comment: Agora eu entendi. Modifiquei o exemplo para fazer o que quer.

Comment: Funcionou sim! Perfeitamente....

Comment: Faz a busca por `4` ou `55`, por exemplo. Algumas buscas não retornam resultado, pois o número do cartão precisa ser válido. Quando não existe resultado, o `input` fica vazio.